# Batch file to open tor browser and several websites

Tags: batch-file, tor, tor-browser-bundle

I'm trying to get a batch file to open tor, but i have the browser bundle and its not technically software, so I don't know how to launch it with a batch file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I put a shortcut to Tor on my desktop, and ran it.

Create a shortcut to Tor, and within a batch file, enter this:

start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\SHORTCUT.lnk" "site1" "site2" "

Just replace SHORTCUTNAME with the name of the shortcut, and site1 and site2 with the sites you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PUSHD command to enter in the browser folder and then the START command to execute the program.

I hope that I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know how to run the internet command in a batch file, but don't know how to run a customised selection.

Try downloading firefox(web browser)(it's great) and then downloading the add on Fox tab. It lets you select a website from your own pre made bundle when you open a new tab.

Sorry for not being able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the unzipped bundle is "App/tor" -- that is the tor binary. However, it would be more helpful to know why you want to launch tor separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\SHORTCUT.lnk" "site1" "site2"
```

For example:

```
start "" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\SHORTCUT.lnk" "google.com" "duckduckgo.com"
```

The suggested answer is slightly wrong (it ends with an extra doublequote)